# Strapi isn't showing both Content Types on GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, content-type, strapi

Context: I'm building a basic blog with **Strapi+Gatsby** following [this tutorial](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-static-blog-with-gatsby-and-strapi).

Problem: I've created the Content Types *'Category'* and *'Post'* (called *'Article'* in the tutorial), *'Post'* has a Relation Field to relate both Content Types (*'Category'* has many *'Posts'*). When trying to access these Content Types via graphQL (*localhost:xxxx/___graphql*) I can't see *'Categories'*, I just see *'Posts'*.

[image: GraphQl]

I would like to query *'Category'* the same way I'm querying *'Post*':

[image: GraphQl Query]

And I've noticed that *'Post'* has a component called *'Category'* because of the Relation Field.

Any idea on why is *'Category'* not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show both Content Types they both have to be indicated in the plugin configuration [rookie mistake, sorry for the question]:

```
resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
options: {     
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL,
    contentTypes: ["category", "article"],
    queryLimit: 1000,
}
```